# Custom UIView in UINavigationbar size calculation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am adding a custom view to navigationItem.titleView that has a **text & an image**.

The problem is, how do I **calculate the size/ space available in navigationitem** so that the custom view does not overlap or exceed the navigationbar itself?

[image: The view contains text & an image]

> Code for custom UIView

I create a UIView & add two elements "a UIlabel & a ImageView".
Right now I am calculating the width based on the length of the string & then I add the image at the end.

If I can determine the available width for the custom view in navigationItem/Navigationbar I can use that instead of the width based on text's length.

```
 func setTitleView(title: String, height: CGFloat, image: UIImage){
    let titleSize = (title as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:textFont])

    arrowImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    titleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, titleSize.width + (arrowImage.bounds.width + padding) * 2 , height/2)
    titleView = UIButton(frame: titleFrame)

    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: titleFrame)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.textColor = textColor
    titleLabel.font = textFont
    titleLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignment.Left
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleView.addSubview(arrowImage)
    titleView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth]
}
```

> In my ViewController

```
//The dropDown is an instance of class containing several other views for dropdown

self.navigationItem.titleView = dropDown.titleView
```

> My Question

**How to calculate the maximum width for navigationItem.titleView so that it does not overlaps the back button & does not overflow from the screen**

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: @IsaacOveracker Try a UIStackView